# NetLogo - how to give each patch an unique identity / plabel / name

Tags: patch, netlogo

I wanted to have a field with many different patches, which have some attributes (e.g. a random (but fixed) amount of food) as well as a name or an ID. 
That is, the top-left patch should have the name "1" (or what ever is feasible), but is not allowed to share this name with an other!

Thanks for your help, I couldn't find anything around.

Answer (score 3):

The patch coordinates already act as a unique id. Thus, `patch 7 10` refers to the patch with `pxcor` 7 and `pycor 10`.

That said, if you'd like a single integer id, you can do something like:

```
patches-own [ id ]

...

(foreach (sort patches) (n-values count patches [?]) [
  ask ?1 [ set id ?2 ]
])
```

`sort patches` creates a list of patches, with the top left patch being first, and continuing left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

`n-values count patches [?]` creates a list of numbers, from 0 to `count patches - 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed for the start.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding assigning a "unique identity" to each patch, my advice is... *don't do it*. Patches are already uniquely identified by the combination of their [`pxcor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#pxcor) and [`pycor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#pycor). So if you want to access the top left patch, you can refer to it as `patch -16 16`.

You should also be aware that references to patches (and turtles, and links) can be stored *directly* in variables. So anytime that you're thinking about storing a "patch id", you should store a reference to the patch. For example, if you want to store the top left patch in a global variable:

```
globals [ top-left-patch ]

to setup
  set top-left-patch patch min-pxcor max-pxcor 
end
```

([`min-pxcor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-pxcor) and [`min-pycor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-pycor) will report `-16` and `16`, or whatever is appropriate to your world's dimension.)

And then, later, you can refer to the stored patch directly:

```
ask top-left-patch [ set pcolor red ]
```

But if you really do want to create an id nonetheless, Bryan's answer is the way to go.